# Windows 10 System sound won't let me play Test button

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, sound-card, system-sounds

So, I have my brand-new Sony headphones in my house, I used Windows 10 on my HP laptop, so the system sound of Windows 10 won't let me play the/a Test button.

I go to the Start menu, Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound > Check system sounds.

When I'm trying to play a system sound using my brand-new Sony headphones w/Realtek audio - I plugged it in - I unmuted the sound volume, I-clicked, double-clicked it, and the system sound button called "▶ Test" won't work on my computer.

** EDIT 9/11/23 **

The system sound button called "▶ Test" now works on my computer (without headphones). I assume I realize that I downloaded `Audio-Win10_Win11-6.0.9360.1.zip` using a ZIP file - I opened it (and also there are large folders and files).

Comment: Does it work going through plugged headphones, internal speakers, and/or amplified speakers?

Comment: Try to install the [Realtek High Definition Audio Driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19336/realtek-high-definition-audio-driver-for-windows-10-windows-11-for-intel-nuc8i7be-nuc8i5be-nuc8i3be-products.html). Create a System Restore backup before installing, just in case.

Comment: I downloaded `Audio-Win10_Win11-6.0.9360.1.zip` using a ZIP file - I opened it (and also there are large files).

Comment: ✅ Done - all set